# Dynamically add an average line in highchart in angular

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

How can I add a line showing average of any plotted graphs in highcharts' stochchart.
Image - [average line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZZ5p.png)
Any way to add this in angular?

Comment: Please add part of the code you have already to get the result done and explain where you get blocked and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the average value and add plot line. Example:

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var yData = this.series[0].yData;
    const sum = yData.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

    this.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
      value: sum / yData.length,
      color: 'red',
      dashStyle: 'longdash'
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vt4muzr2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis